# CoreData - should I pass an existing NSNumber to set the attribute of an entity, or create a new one?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm starting with CoreData and I have a question :
I have an array with NSNumber objects in it. I need to create an entity `Event` for each object with only one attribute `eventNumber` which should also be an NSNumber.

Can I pass the object of my array like this :

```
for (int i = 0, i<[myArray count], i++){
   Event *newEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedContext:managedContext];
   [newEvent setEventNumber:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]]
}
[myArray release]
```

or is it necessary to create a new NSNumber like that :

```
for (int i = 0, i<[myArray count], i++){
   Event *newEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedContext:managedContext];
   [newEvent setEventNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue]]
}
[myArray release]
```

Thank you for your help.

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create a new `NSNumber` for this purpose; your first option is correct.

You could, however, simplify your loop by using [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocfastenumeration.html):

```
for (NSNumber *num in myArray) {
   Event *newEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedContext:managedContext];
   [newEvent setEventNumber:num]
}
```